# remove selected item from recyclerView on click delete image icon

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I want remove selected item from recyclerView list.
In my list I have delete image icon each row and I want delete item when clicked delete image icon. How can do it?
My adapter code this is see my code how can do it:
thank you

```
 public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private List<Items> items=new ArrayList<>();

public ListAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item,parent,false);

    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindItem(items.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return items.size();
}

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private ImageView editIcon;
    private ImageView deleteIcon;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        editIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_edit);
        deleteIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_delete);
    }

    public void bindItem(Items item){
        titleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
    }

    public void removeItem(int position){
        items.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void addItem(Items item){
    items.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(items.size()-1);
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code

```
public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        editIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_edit);
        deleteIcon=itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_delete);
        // put this code
        deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(getAdapterPosition())
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above does the job, but it is always better to use interface callback for easier implementation and code modularity. Below is the code that I like to write for removing the list item from the activity. In this method, you don't have to alter much code of the adapter class, and in case you want to do more complicated such as: remove the list element only when the element from the Firebase database is removed, this method does this job perfectly.
Here is a code snippet

```java
new DeclinedClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void declinedClick(int position, View v) {
        fbDB.getReference("news_requests").child(articles.get(position).getNewsID()).removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                articles.remove(position);
                if (article_req_rv.getAdapter() != null) {
                    article_req_rv.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

you make a interface for it

```
public interface DeclinedClickListener {
    void declinedClick(int position, View v);
}
```

Use this inteface in recyclerview

```
holder.declined_btx.setOnClickListener(l -> {
    declinedClickListener.declinedClick(position, l);
});
```